# Obtener los mismos valores de un select generado dinámicamente en otro select

Tags: javascript, php

tengo un pequeño problema, les explico. Tengo un `<select>` cuyos `<option>` se generan dinámicamente de valores de una tabla sql usando ajax, php.
En mi formulario el código es el siguiente:

La parte de `<div id="temas"></div>` es donde se obtiene el resultado dinámico con ajax y php (es el que encierro en rojo en la imagen, eso si funciona). Cada vez que le doy clic al botón "Agregar campos" se añaden una serie de inputs (lo que encerré en azul) y necesito que también aparezca el select  (el que encerré en rojo) con sus respectivos valores, como verán en lo que encerré en azul el select no está.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<div class="col s12 m12 l12">
  <div id="form-with-validation" class="card card card-default scrollspy">
    <div id="show_alert"></div>

    <div class="listalis card-content" id="lista">
      <h4 class="card-title">Secuencia didáctica</h4>
      <div class="row">

        <div class="input-field col m4 s6">
          <i class="material-icons prefix">event</i>
          <input class="fecha" id="icon_prefix2" type="date" name="fecha[]" required>
          <label for="icon_prefix2">Fecha</label>
        </div>
        <div id="temas">

        </div>

        <div class="input-field col m4 s6">
          <i class="material-icons prefix">keyboard</i>
          <input class="est" id="icon_prefix3" type="text" name="estrategia[]" required>
          <label for="icon_prefix3">Estrategia utilizada</label>
        </div>

        <div class="input-field col m4 s6">
          <i class="material-icons prefix">laptop_windows</i>
          <textarea class="materialize-textarea acte" name="ActE[]" required></textarea>
          <label for="icon_prefix4">Actividad de enseñanza</label>
        </div>

        <div class="input-field col m4 s6">
          <i class="material-icons prefix">local_library</i>
          <textarea class="materialize-textarea acta" name="ActA[]" required></textarea>
          <label for="icon_prefix4">Actividad de aprendizaje</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col m2 s3">
          <button class="waves-effect waves-light btn gradient-45deg-amber-amber z-depth-4 mr-1 mb-2" id="limpiar">Limpiar</button>
        </diV>

      </div>

    </div>
    <div>
      <input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" id="add_btn" value="Guardar planeación" />
    </div>
```

Aquí mi código de js con el que obtengo los inputs dinámicamente, es el código en el que necesito agregar los valores del select que encerré en rojo:

```
$(".add_item_btn").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#lista").append(`                                    
                                    <div class="row append_item">
                                    <div class="lista card-content">
                                    <div class="input-field col m4 s6">
                                    <i class="material-icons prefix">event</i>
                                    <input  class="fecha2"  id="icon_prefix2" type="date" name="fecha[]" required>
                                    <label for="icon_prefix2">Fecha</label>
                                    </div>
                                        
                                          <div id="temas">
                                        
                                        
                                          </div>
                                          
                                    <div class="input-field col m4 s6">
                                    <i class="material-icons prefix">keyboard</i>
                                    <input class="est2"  id="icon_prefix3" type="text" name="estrategia[]" required>
                                    <label for="icon_prefix3">Estrategia utilizada</label>
                                    </div>
                                         
                                    <div class="input-field col m4 s6">
                                    <i class="material-icons prefix">laptop_chromebook</i>
                                    <input class="acte2" id="icon_prefix4" type="text" name="ActE[]" required>
                                    <label for="icon_prefix4">Actividad de enseñanza</label>
                                    </div>
                                        
                                    <div class="input-field col m4 s6">
                                    <i class="material-icons prefix">local_library</i>
                                    <input class="acta2"  id="icon_prefix5" type="text" name="ActA[]" required>
                                    <label for="icon_prefix5">Actividad de aprendizaje</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="input-field col m2 s3">
                                    <input class="waves-effect waves-light btn gradient-45deg-red-pink z-depth-4 mr-1 mb-2 remove_item_btn" type="button" value="Quitar campos"/>
                                    </diV>
                                     <div class="input-field col m2 s3">
                                        <button class="waves-effect waves-light btn gradient-45deg-amber-amber z-depth-4 mr-1 mb-2" id="limpiar">Limpiar</button>
                                        </diV>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>`);
});
```

Pensé que poniendo lo de `<div id="temas">` en el js funcionaría pero no, si alguien supiera como podría funcionar agradezco su respuesta.
Por cierto el código php con el que obtengo los valores con ajax (eso si funciona) es el siguiente por si se necesita

```js
<?php 
    $unidad = htmlentities($_POST['unidadselect'],ENT_QUOTES,'utf-8');
    $materia = htmlentities($_POST['materiaselect'],ENT_QUOTES,'utf-8');
    
    
        $sql_temas = "SELECT Id FROM unidades WHERE unidad = :unidad AND IdMateria = :materia";
            $temas = $pdo->prepare($sql_temas);
            $temas->bindParam(':unidad', $unidad, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $temas->bindParam(':materia', $materia, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $exitotemas = $temas->execute();
            $row = $temas->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $idunidad = $row['Id'];
            
            
            $sql_temas2 = "SELECT nombre FROM temas WHERE IdUnidad = :idunidad";
            $temas2 = $pdo->prepare($sql_temas2);
            $temas2->bindParam(':idunidad', $idunidad, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $exitotemas2 = $temas2->execute();
            
        $cadena2="
       <div class='input-field col m4 s6'>
                <select class='select2 browser-default tema' name='tema[]' required>
                <option data-icon='book' selected>Selecciona el tema</option>
        ";
        
    
         while($ver2 = $temas2->FETCH(PDO::FETCH_NUM)){
            $cadena2 = $cadena2.'<option value='.$ver2[0].'>'.($ver2[0]).'</option></div>';
        }
    
        echo  $cadena2."</select></div>
    ";

    ?>
```

Comment: Tu planteamiento es confuso: *El problema es que cada vez que le doy clic al botón "Agregar campos" que encerré en azul se van agregando inputs y necesito que también se vaya el select con los valores, como verán en lo que encerré en azul el select no está.* Por favor, pulsa en [edit] y explica con más claridad el problema. ¿Qué significa *que el select se vaya con los valores*? ¿Para dónde tiene que *irse*?

Comment: Ese elemento dinámico no se carga ya que al darle click al botón **Agregar Campos** generas HTML mediante JQuery, el **select** lo genera **PHP**, para ello deberías hacer nuevamente otra petición Ajax para que genere dicho select, de lo contrario nunca se generara.

Comment: Pero solo sería como clonar ese select con su contenido, debe haber alguna manera de lograrlo, al final de cuentas sus valores ya fueron cargados, los demás serían como hijos o algo así

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Respondo a mi pregunta, resulta que no era tan difícil, pero si un poco complejo de resolver (al menos para mi) pero aquí está la solución por si alguna vez alguien tiene un problema similar.
Con el `select` generado dinámicamente ya no es necesario generarlo cada vez, basta con clonarlo pues al final sus valores son html generados por php.
Para disponer de todo el HTML incluido en el objeto seleccionado, necesitamos lo siguiente:

```
var clon = $('<div />').append( $('#temas').clone() ).remove().html();
```

Esto funciona de la siguiente forma:

1. Clonamos el elemento que hemos seleccionado.
2. Creamos un div a modo de contenedor temporal para envolver el elemento clonado.
3. Obtenemos el HTML del nuevo div que ahora si contiene todo el marcado.
4. Una vez tenemos los datos, eliminamos el nodo del DOM para limpiarlo.

Y en el `append` donde genero dinámicamente los inputs mando a llamar mi variable

```
    $("#lista").append(`                                    
                                    
                                    <div class="row append_item">
                                    <div class="lista card-content">
                                    <h4 class="card-title"><b>Actividad ${contador++}</b></h4>
                                    <div class="input-field col m4 s6">
                                    <i class="material-icons prefix">event</i>
                                    <input  class="fecha2"  id="icon_prefix2" type="date" name="fecha[]" required>
                                    <label for="icon_prefix2">Fecha</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="temas">
                                        ${clon} 
                                    <div>
                                   <div class="input-field col m4 s6">
                                    <i class="material-icons prefix">keyboard</i>
                                    <input class="est2"  id="icon_prefix3" type="text" name="estrategia[]" required>
                                    <label for="icon_prefix3">Estrategia utilizada</label>
                                    </div>
                                         
                                    <div class="input-field col m4 s6">
                                    <i class="material-icons prefix">laptop_chromebook</i>
                                    <input class="acte2" id="icon_prefix4" type="text" name="ActE[]" required>
                                    <label for="icon_prefix4">Actividad de enseñanza</label>
                                    </div>
                                        
                                    <div class="input-field col m4 s6">
                                    <i class="material-icons prefix">local_library</i>
                                    <input class="acta2"  id="icon_prefix5" type="text" name="ActA[]" required>
                                    <label for="icon_prefix5">Actividad de aprendizaje</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="input-field col m2 s3">
                                    <input class="waves-effect waves-light btn gradient-45deg-red-pink z-depth-4 mr-1 mb-2 remove_item_btn" type="button" value="Quitar campos"/>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>`);


});
```

Con esto tengo el `select` clonado cada vez que agrego los inputs.